# Looking for: non-parametric multivariate repeated measure test

Tags: multivariate-analysis, nonparametric

I am looking for a *non-parametric version of the multivariate repeated measures GLM procedure*.

I have ordered symptoms of a disease at 2 time points (0-3), and I want to show that they change differentially (in response to something that happens to the whole sample during the 2 time points). If my symptoms were metric, I could run a multivariate repeated measures GLM, and if the interaction term symptom*time is significant, I have differential change of symptoms over time.

The Friedman test - a non-parametric version of the repeated measure GLM - does not suffice, because it can either compare medians of multiple DVs at the same time, or medians of the same DV over time, but it cannot handle multivariate + repeated measure (at least I haven't found a way to do that).

Software I have installed and can work with is R, SPSS, and MPLUS available. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't ordered logit be what you are looking for?

Comment: Ordered logit might be the link function, but in what software can I perform an ordered logit multivariate repeated measure analysis?

Comment: Would this: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/repolr/repolr.pdf be your answer? I have never worked with it, but it looks as it might, pardon the pun, fit to your requirements.

Comment: It allows modeling _one_ ordered DV over 2 time points (which you can do with 3 clicks in SPSS via Friedman test), but not of _several_ DVs over 2 time points :(

Comment: Aren't you looking for a generalized linear mixed effects model (i.e., glmer in the lme4 package)? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf

Comment: I know lme4, but haven't found a way to run lme4 (or, for that matter, clmm from the package 'ordinal') with more than 1 DV at a time.